# Android adding geopoints with delay on google map

Tags: android, android-mapview

What I want to do is adding GeoPoints on a google mapView. This is what my code now looks like:

```
    public ArrayList getLocations() {
        ArrayList<OverlayItem> locations = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        /* open SQLite database aanmaken als deze al dan niet bestaat */ 

    SQLiteDatabase myDB = openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null); 
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("data", 0);
    String route_id = String.valueOf( preferences.getInt("route_id", 0));

    String[] resultColumns = new String[] { "_id", "route_id","naam", "lng", "lat" };
    String whereClause = "route_id=?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] {route_id};

        Cursor cursor = myDB.query(DATABASE_TABLE_LOCATIES, resultColumns, whereClause,
                whereArgs, null, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            String naam = cursor.getString(2);
            Double lat = cursor.getDouble(4);
            Double lon = cursor.getDouble(3);
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6),(int) (lon * 1E6));
            locations.add(new OverlayItem(point, naam,naam));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());



   return locations;
    }

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  InterestingLocations funPlaces = new InterestingLocations(marker);
  mapView.getOverlays().add(getLocations);
}
```

This code is putting all my pointers at once on the mapView. I would like a small delay when putting each pointer on the map.
How could I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define global variable,

```
private Timer myTimer;
```

add this inside `onCreate()` method:

```
myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TimerMethod();
        }

    }, 0, 1000);

}
```

and add this function in the class:

```
private void TimerMethod()
{
    this.runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
}
```

and define this as global variable:

```
private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
public void run() {

    //here is your job, instead of writing this [mapView.getOverlays().add(getLocations);]

    //you have to create a loop for the list returned by getLocations() to add them in the timer one by one
}
};
```

Comment: +1 correct. But these are class variables, not global. Global would be `public` and `static`.

Comment: true mate, global on the class I meant, since we are talking in specific area.